# can't require JS files client side

Tags: javascript, html, npm

I'm trying to learn how to make an NPM package, I thought it would be easy: create JS files with objects literals, export modules and then on the other end, have a user require the file and use the object: `objectname.method`. Problem is my intended user is going to be using my library for making html5 games. I'm not experienced making client side apps and don't truly understand how importing and requiring files works without these methods.

how would I accomplish this?
I thought i could do like nodeJS and make files via module.exports = {}

an example of my Object I'm trying to export. I'm honestly winging it so it probably is completely wrong.

```
//modEx.js
 module.exports = {
   drawBall: (ctx, x, y, ballRadius) => {
     ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  },

  hello: function() {
   return "HELLO";
  }
};
```

then I'm testing by trying to import/require in another file and opening an html file with script tags.

```
//example.js
const mod_ex = require("./mod_ex");
console.log('hello',mod_ex.hello); #=> hello, undefined
```

Comment: you can't do it in a browser without a blunder check Browserify or Webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to bundle your lib with Webpack or any other bundler.

Comment: I've tried learning webpack, most tutorials go over my head but I'm reading its docs now i think i can manage

Answer (score 1):

Either bundle the js files with webpack or parcel or other bundlers or just use `<script type="module">` and you will be able to use es6 import. But support is like 80% of all browsers.